# I'm struggling with making and using Python classes

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone explain to me why the following code prints out nothing?

```
class Deck(object):

    def __init__(self, deck):
        self.deck = getDeck(deck)


    def getDeck(deck):
        with open(deck, "rU") as csvfile:
            cardReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            newDeck = []
            for row in cardReader:
                for x in range(int(row['NumberOfCards'])):
                    newDeck.append(row)

            removedKeyDeck = []
            for x in range(len(newDeck)):
                r = dict(newDeck[x])
                del r['NumberOfCards']
                removedKeyDeck.append(r)
        return removedKeyDeck


playerDeck = Deck('deck1.csv')


print playerDeck
```

I'm trying to create a deck list from the `deck1.csv` file. I know that the `getDeck` function works, but that I'm not using `class` structure correctly. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Something seems to be broken here with the indentation of the code.

Comment: @languitar I've fixed the indentation - just awaiting a peer review..

Comment: Apparently there was and the below answerer fixed it. I haven't quite got the hang of block code posting on Stack.

Comment: i doubt it prints nothing. i'd suppose it prints sometinhg like `<__main__.Deck object at 0xb7310620>`

Comment: You are correct @njzk2. As noted, though, I did not have the `getDeck` function inside of my class structure. I'm new to using a `class` in my code, so I'm winging it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the indentation in your question (if it was how it was originally it needed fixing...)

Try this:

```
self.deck = self.getDeck(deck)
```

and the following will print out the `deck` attribute you set in the `__init__` function.

```
print playerDeck.deck
```

Comment: It was broken...but I didn't know it. I had created that function before creating the class structure, so I didn't know I needed to move the `getDeck` function into the class. All fixed now. Much appreciated.

Comment: I Just did, had to wait for 5 minutes before it allowed me to accept. Thanks again! @kisamoto

Answer (score 0):

What happens in your code is that you create an instance of the class Deck for the deck1.csv file and due to the automatic invocation of the init method, also the getDeck method is called. However, you are not using that return value right now. Your print statement only prints out the instance of Deck that you created. If you want to leave the class untouched as it is, then calling

```
print playerDeck.deck
```

will do something meaningful.